# How to use case or if with in Where clause in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to use case or if with in Where clause in SQL SERVER?

```
DECLARE
@Sta        int
Set @Sta    = 1

SELECT TOP 1000 
         [No]
        ,[Material]
        ,[Material Description]
        ,[Procurement Type]

  FROM  [PMLite].[dbo].[zSTO:8/22/2016]
  WHERE IF @Sta = 1
        [Procurement Type] IN ('F','E')
        ELSE @Sta   = 2
        [Procurement Type]= 'F'
```

Can anyone help for this case..

Comment: Please explain the logic of your `WHERE` clause.  Do you expect it to make an assignment?

Comment: if the parameter value is 1 then display that contain F or E

Comment: But if parameter value is 2 then only display F

Comment: A `CASE` expression must return a single scalar value.

Comment: General advice, leave case (and  if) out of where clauses. Use AND/OR instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `if` or `case` statements in `where` clause in the manner you're trying to do it.

But in fact you don't need these statements since your condition can be rewritten using logical operators as:

```
 WHERE (@Sta = 1 and [Procurement Type] IN ('F','E'))
        or (@Sta = 2 and [Procurement Type]= 'F')
```

Comment: It's worth noting that what the OP is trying to do is not possible.  `if` and `case` statements *cannot* be used in that manner.  By your wording *"In your case there is no need in using `if` or `case` statements..."*, it makes it sound like what he was trying to do was actually possible, just unnecessary - which is incorrect.

Comment: It is possible to have a case expression in the where clause, but it's generally a bad idea.

Comment: @jarlh It's possible to have a case statement in the where clause, true.  But not to logically control which `where` statements are used as the OP had attempted.

Comment: @Siyual, OP's dysfunctional where clause can be re-written to use a case expression, but that's nothing I recommend. (Case expression, not case statement.)

Comment: @Siyual Reasonable comment concerning potentially misleading wording, thanks. Fixed...

Answer (score 0):

The `OR` statement above works, another method is to use dynamic sql

```
DECLARE
@Sta        int
Set @Sta    = 1;


DECLARE @sqlstring NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
SELECT TOP 1000 
         [No]
        ,[Material]
        ,[Material Description]
        ,[Procurement Type]

  FROM  [PMLite].[dbo].[zSTO:8/22/2016]';

IF @Sta = 1
    SET @sqlstring = @sqlstring + N'WHERE [Procurement Type] IN (''F'',''E'')'
ELSE
    SET @sqlstring = @sqlstring + N'WHERE [Procurement Type]= ''F''';

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlstring;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing the same:

```
WHERE [Procurement Type] = (CASE WHEN @Sta = 1 THEN 'E' END)
   OR [Procurement Type] = (CASE WHEN @Sta = 1 OR @Sta = 2 THEN 'F' END)
```

Comment: Thanks @Pinwar13 but the first answer is still simpliest

Comment: There is E and F for @Sta = 1